# hover over an animation menu and click a menu item in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hover, click

I am trying to hover over an Animation Menu and select an Item in the Menu. I tried to perform hover on the menu by xpath first and perform click on the menu item by xpath as below.

```
WebElement ch = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-item-24463']/a"));
builder.moveToElement(ch).perform();
WebElement ch1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-item-24463']/div/ul/li[1]/a"));
ch1.click();
```

I get an exception

org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view

I also tried to chain the actions as below

```
builder.moveToElement(ch).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-item-24463']/div/ul/li[1]/a"))).click().build().perform();
```

which also throws the same exception.

Any Idea to achieve the click in Animation Menu item?

Comment: Can you share website where you are doing this? Apply some wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Locate and Store Web Elements**

```
WebElement ch = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-item-24463']/a"));
WebElement ch1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-item-24463']/div/ul/li[1]/a"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
```

**Perform hover**

```
builder.moveToElement(ch).perform();
```

**Wait for the Element to appear in the view & Perform Click**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ch1));
ch1.click();
```